# Is it possible to store base64 of a file in javascript object and send it to backend using ajax?

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader

I am just trying to upload image file in base64 format by storing it in a js object. But the problem here is the object property 'baseData' doesn't fill with the DataURL of the image. If the way I mentioned below is possible, please suggest the solution to fill the 'baseData' property.

What I am doing is storing the 'type' (image or video, not extensions) and DataURL of the file in the object(fileDataObject) and pushing the object to an array(blobData), and returning the same at the end of the function.

Thanks in advance

```
var filesAccept = filesValidator($("#file-upload")[0].files);

       if(filesAccept !== false){

       var fd = new FormData();
       fd.append("files", filesAccept)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "receiver.php",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (result) {
                  console.log(result);
                },
              });
}

    function filesValidator(f) {
    if (f.length === 0) {
            $("#error-info").text("Please select some images or videos.");
            return false;
        } else if(f.length !== 0) {
            var blobData = [];
            var fileType;
            $("#error-info").text("");
    
            var n = 10;
            if (f.length < 10) {// checking if files count less than 10
                n = f.length;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            fileType = f[i].type.split("/");
            if(fileType[1] === "gif"){
                return false;
            } else if (fileType[0] === "image") {// if file is images
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var src = e.target.result.split(",")[1];
                    console.log(src);
                    var fileDataObject = {
                        baseData : src,
                        type : "image"
                    };
                    blobData.push(JSON.stringify(fileDataObject));
                }
                
                reader.readAsDataURL(f[i]);
            } else if(fileType[0] === "video") { //if file is video
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var src = e.target.result.split(",")[1];
                    var fileDataObject = {
                        baseData : src,
                        type : "video"
                    };
                    blobData.push(JSON.stringify(fileDataObject));
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(f[i]);
            }
            console.log(blobData);
        }
        return blobData;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this.  What do you see?  Do you get the image's base64 on the console log?  Did you see that you could combine the two branches of the `if` by setting `type : fileType[0]` ?

Comment: I am getting base64 on console.log of src after assigning to it. But when console.log of the object, there is nothing showing.

Comment: Cool, then what doesn't work?

Comment: I want to send the array containing base64 of files to the backend using ajax. But when receiving the array at the backend there are only the brackets(this one -> [])`fd.append("files", filesAccept);$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "receiver.php", data: fd,
 processData: false, contentType: false, dataType: "text", success: function (result) {
 console.log(result); }, });`

Comment: I don't know what that code is for.  Perhaps you should amend the question.

Comment: Brackets are receiving when using `JSON.stringify()` but when not using it there is nothing even the brackets.

Comment: Does the `console.log(blobData);` loop OK?

Comment: Yes the loop is ok

Comment: Sorry, I meant "does it look ok".

Comment: I'm a little bit confused.  Is this code the sender or the receiver?  What does the other end look like?

Comment: This code is the sender. I am trying to send the base64 of an image file and with PHP function `file_put_contents(base64_of_image)` on the other end, will create the image file with jpeg or png extension. This is what I want. But  I can't send the array containing base64 to the backend. I think that the error is on the array returning from the `fileValidator()` function.